# get value of a specific column in Telerik Multi column combobox

Tags: c#, telerik

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="drpEmployeeItemID" runat="server" DropDownWidth="825px" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" Height="190px">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="col1">ItemName</li>
                            <li class="col2">ColorName</li>
                            <li class="col3">StyleName</li>
                            <li class="col4">BrandName</li>
                            <li class="col5">ModelName</li>
                            <li class="col6">LotNo</li>
                            <li class="col7">BatchNo</li>
                            <li class="col8">CountryName</li>
                        </ul>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="col1">
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemName")%></li>
                            <li class="col2">
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ColorName")%></li>
                            <li class="col3">
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StyleName")%></li>
                            <li class="col4">
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BrandName")%></li>
                            <li class="col5">
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ModelName")%></li>
                            <li class="col6">
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LotNo")%></li>
                            <li class="col7">
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BatchNo")%></li>
                            <li class="col8">
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CountryName")%></li>
                        </ul>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:RadComboBox>
            </div>
```

I have to get the `LotNo` of the selected Item. I have tried GetSelectedItem / getselected value. but no selection of the specific column.

Answer (score 1):

Set `OnDataBound` event

```
telerik:RadComboBox ID="drpEmployeeItemID" OnDataBound="drpEmployeeItemID_DataBound"
```

Define handler

```
protected void drpEmployeeItemID_DataBound(object sender, RadComboBoxItemEventArgs e)
{
   e.Item.Text = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["ItemName"].ToString() ;
   e.Item.Value = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["LotNo"].ToString(); 

   // set attributes
   e.Item.Attributes["ColorName"] = dataItem["ColorName"];    
   e.Item.Attributes["StyleName"] = dataItem["StyleName"];
   ...
}
```

Use the text and value in the butto

```
var itemName = drpEmployeeItemID.Text;
var value = drpEmployeeItemID.SelectedValue;

// get item
var item = drpEmployeeItemID.FindItemByValue(value);
var colorName = item.Attributes["ColorName"];
```

**Edited**
There is now way to get original `DataItem` after data bound. If you want to add more properties to an item, you can use `Attributes` collection to store them.

Another way is to save your original datasource in the session and find data item by selected value.

Comment: 1) I have to select the value while i click the save button. 2) I need to have all the column value of the radcombobox. Atleast id as value, name as text, and lotid as ............